# SQL server datetime datatype (default time)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

possibly a very silly question here but lets say:

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

set @startdate = '2013-05-01'
set @enddate = '2014-04-30'

select * from table 
where table.timestamp between @startdate AND @enddate
```

Like I said, silly question, but would this generate all records between 1st May 2013 00:00:00 to 30th April 2013 00:00:00? i.e exactly one year? Or, would I need to change the enddate to 23:59:59, to include the 30th as the last day?

thanks, and apologies again for what may seem a silly question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an index on `table.timestamp`, the fastest solution is probably to increase the end date by one day and use `>=` and `<` instead of `BETWEEN`:

```
select * from table 
where table.timestamp >= @startdate AND table.timestamp < DATEADD(day,1,@enddate)
```

Any formulas used on `table.timestamp` (like `truncate`, `cast`, etc.) will negate the use of an index unless the index is based on the same expression.

Comment: Thank you, this would include the last day of the year (30th April 14?). cheers

Comment: The that would include data up to (but not including) `2014-05-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: FWIW, simply casting a datetime to a date is still sargable.  If you are joining to a large table of startdate/enddate pairs, cast can be better than dateadd. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:-

```
select * from table 
where cast(table.timestamp as date) between @startdate AND @enddate
```

Whatever be the data in `table.timestamp`, the data will show up.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to test:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), somedates DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #temp
        ( somedates )
VALUES  ( '2014-06-13 14:20:34' )

SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE somedates BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-13'
--No Results returned

SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE somedates BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND DATEADD(ms,-1,'2014-06-14')
--One result returned

DROP TABLE #temp
```

So if you want to include records on April 30th, you do need to increase the end date by 1.